# How to remove Note to seller function on paypal express checkout?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

How to remove Note to seller function on paypal express checkout ?

I use paypal express checkout for my store.
I want to hide Note to seller function on paypal page.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

If you pass 'allownote=0' parameter with your checkout request it should disable the note option.

```
&ALLOWNOTE=0
```

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/